# resolve-url-loader error when using image in jsx files in React Application

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm rewriting old code and I want to move image definition from .css files ( `background: url('./../images/something.svg')` ) to .jsx and also I'm removing webpack and want to use only react-script. When I move the image to .jsx file that I first import the image  `import something from '../../../images/something.png';`  and then I use it  `<img src={something} alt="Something" />` after this I'm getting error `Module build failed (from ./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js): Error: resolve-url-loader: error processing CSS file://C:\dev\my-project\src\images\something.png:1:1: Unknown word` or `Unclosed string`  in the end

Answer (score 0):

When you import images to jsx file your syntax will look like this

```
import img from '../../../images/something.png'

const App = () => {
  return(
    <>
      <img src={img}/>
    </>
  );
}
```

when you import you add image to "variable" at this case it's img

Answer (score 0):

As you import `footer` in this line `import footer from '../../../images/something.png';`, you must use `footer` as a `variable` in the `attribute`'s value of `img` tag because it specifies the path to the image.

For example,

**Code must be**

```
<img src={footer} alt="Something" />
```

**Instead of**

```
<img src={something} alt="Something" />
```

Comment: thank you, it was my mistake I corrected it in my post 
I have it as you wrote but I'm getting an error anyway

Comment: Well, you can navigate to the package `node_modules/resolve-url-loader` and open `index.js` file. Under `var options` you should change `removeCR` from "false" to "true" and then you can try.